# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1 , for videoplayer widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In this shouldn't the valid range be 1 as at index 0 I have placed a button and at index 1 it's the video file. I tried other variations but I am not sure where the error persists as it's giving the same error for [index-1], [index], [index + 1] .

Add video class:

```
class _addVideoState extends State<addVideo> {
  bool uploading = false;
  double val = 0;
  CollectionReference? vidRef;
  firebase_storage.Reference? ref;
  File? video;
  VideoPlayerController? videoPlayerController;
  VideoPlayerController? INvideoPlayerController;

  
  List<File> _video = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add video'),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                uploading = true;
              });

              uploadFile().whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pop());
            },
            child: Text(
              'Upload Video',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _video.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            INvideoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(
                _video[index + 1])
              ..setLooping(true)
              ..initialize().then((value) => INvideoPlayerController!.play());
            return index == 0
                ? Center(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          !uploading ? chooseVideo() : null;
                          print(_video);
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Test',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        )),
                  )
                : AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: INvideoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: VideoPlayer(INvideoPlayerController!),
                  );
           
          }),
    );
  }
```

chooseVideo(this is where I am adding to my list):

```
chooseVideo() async {
    ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

    final pickedFile = await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _video.add(File(pickedFile!.path));
    });
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(pickedFile!.path))
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {
           
          }))
      ..setLooping(true)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        
        videoPlayerController!.play();
      });
    print(pickedFile.path);
    print(File(pickedFile.path));
    print('Kavya-choosevideo-videoPlayerController :   $videoPlayerController');
    if (pickedFile.path == null) retrieveLostData();
  }
```

Comment: Can you please include your `chooseVideo` function code?

Answer (score 0):

On the first build of the widget your `_video` list is empty but you are forcing an

```dart
itemCount: _video.length + 1
```

in your ListView, so you are forcing one item to be added to your ListView and immediately giving it the video file value of

```dart
_video[index + 1]
```

It's important to note here that your are not assigning a value to `_video` but you are requesting the array item at index `index + 1` which does not exist. At this point there is no items in this array and I don't see any code that added to it, so please add it to your answer if you have it, if not you need to populate the array before you can use it.

In any case, you need to add an if statement that displays another widget when the `_video` list is empty

```dart
if(_video.isEmpty)
// Show another widget
else
// Display video player
```

Comment: I am unable to add if-else as I have already added if-else for elevated button and aspect ratio,  how can I add another if-else in my code?